persistent_bottom_nav_bar-5.0.2 Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'
/C:/Users/*****/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/persistent_bottom_nav_bar-5.0.2/lib/neumorphic_package_by_serge_software/neumorphic_card.dart:57:57: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.

'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/C:/flutter/FlutterDev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.

    final color = decoration.color ?? Theme.of(context).backgroundColor;
I had tried out:

flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub get

not resolved

If you are trying to set a background color for a card then try to use Theme.of(context).cardColor or if used themedata then use Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor
